# Combine a number with a date without showing 'year' as 1900

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, concatenation, excel-2013

I'm trying to convert a number and date together in Excel 2013 as one number.  Example:

Cell A1 contains a number `123456` and B1 contains a date `02/07/1976`.
I need to combine both so A1 reads `12345602071976` (without the slashes in the date).

Instead, I'm getting `1234561900` and was getting a weird error that showed something like...`123456+16`? I believe I need to insert blank columns and separate out the date and then create a formula to combine everything but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=A1&RIGHT("0"&DAY(B1),2)&RIGHT("0"&MONTH(B1),2)&YEAR(B1)
```

Comment: OMG, YES it worked!!! You are AWESOME!!  I entered the formula in c1 and it workd...how to I get that same outcome in a1? I've lost sleep and spent the entire day trying to figure this out until I came across your site about 2 hours ago, and you promptly replied! I so much appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
=A1&TEXT(DATEVALUE(B1),"mmddyyyy")
```

Note: assumes your date is text. If the date in B1 is actually a true Excel date, then this:

```
=A1&TEXT(B1,"mmddyyyy")
```

Note: if you want the days to come before the months then reverse the `mmdd` to `ddmm`.

Comment: @Tammy Please tell me if you were able to get this answer to work.